Laravel Livewire post request does not work with localization web URL prefix
I have a problem with setting Laravel 11 locale and livewire 3 working together. The problem is that the Livewire post request 'POST: livewire/update' fails, I'm getting a 404 response but if I disable the locale prefix and Middleware, livewire works fine.
bootstrap\app.php
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
        then: function () {
            $locale = request()->segment(1);
            if(in_array($locale,config('app.locales'))){
                Route::middleware('web')
                    ->prefix($locale)
                    ->name('webroutes')
                    ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
            }
        },
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->append(\App\Http\Middleware\SetLanguage::class);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {

    })->create();

SetLanguage.php Middleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $locale = $request->segment(1);
        if (!in_array($locale, config('app.locales'))) {
            return redirect(url(getCurrentUrlWithLocale(config('app.fallback_locale'))));
        }
        app()->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}

After troubleshooting I found out that the Liveware post request doesn't work with the locale language prepended on the URL e.g. domain.test/fr/todo. Can someone help me to either exclude post 'livewire/update' from locale functionalities or make the post work request work with a prepend locale URL?

One of the solution you can do is

You can just use a callback to register your routes:

->withRouting(
    commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
    using: function () {
        Route::middleware(['web','locale'])->group(base_path('routes/web.php'))
    }
)->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->alias([
        'locale' => SetLanguage::class
    ])
})

Take note that the health (/up) route will not be register so you can just also define it inside the callback.
Routing Customization

Wrap the routes defined in the web.php inside the Route::middleware()->group(fn () => ...)

Route::middleware(SetLanguage::class)->group(function () {
   // register routes here
})



Good attempt but the issue with Livewire still persists The moment the URL turns from domain. Test/todo to domain. Test/en/todo, all Livewire requests returns 404, regardless of how I wrap other get routes.

Your answer is correct but it needs a little change on the router's wrapper. I added both 'web' and 'locale' aliases on the routes wrapper, which fixed the problem.

I have done these updates
app.php

    return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
        ->withRouting(
            web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
            commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
            health: '/up',
            then: function () {
                $locale = request()->segment(1);
                if(in_array($locale,config('app.locales'))){
                    Route::middleware('web')
                        ->prefix($locale)
                        ->name('webroutes')
                        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
                }
            },
        )
        ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
            $middleware->alias([
                'locale'=>\App\Http\Middleware\SetLanguage::class
            ]);
        })
        ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    
        })->create();

web.php

    Route::middleware(['web','locale'])
        ->prefix('{locale}')
        ->where(['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'])
        ->group(function () {
            // Your localized routes go here
        });


As long as your localized routes are inside the wrapper, Livewire routes won't be interrupted with prefixes.
